# Adding fixed effects in STATA

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model

I wanted to include country fixed effects in my regression model. So this is the STATA code:

encode country, g(country_number)
regress lifeexp logGDPpercap i.country_number

The final estimation would give a bunch of country coefficients. I have 20 of them. According to my understanding, there shouldn't be all 20 country coefficients as well as a constant term as that would lead to infinite possiblilities and thus the model cannot be estimated. In my results for one country A, the estimated coeffecient is 0 and standard error says (.). So is this the country that got automatically dropped? Thanks in advance

Comment: How many observations do you have in your data?  Yes, in stata, by default, the first level of a factor variable is dropped from the design matrix when fitting a regression model, so that you can obtain a unique solution to the regression equation, but it usually doesn't show up in the estimated coefficient table as youv'e described.  Is country A the first variable that appears country_number?  Is it possible you have fewer observations than parameters you are attempting to estimate?

Comment: Also, have you run frequencies and descriptive statistics on your data?  I'm suspecting that if you your observations $\ge$ parameters you're trying to estimate, then the issue might be all missing data on your lifeexp and logGDPpercap variables for Country A.  Since it looks like your data might be in the public domain (e.g. life-expectancy data, GDP per capita, and country), can you post the data or provide a link to an online source of the data, so we can take a closer look?   Then we'll be able to diagnose the exact cause of the problem without making educated guesses.